# Does del (x, y) delete the tuple (x, y) or the individual variables x and y?

Tags: python, del

Assume the following code:

```
lid = foo(guz)
tym = bar(jug)

hig(lid, tym)

del (lid, tym)
```

Will the newly created anonymous tuple `(lid, tym)` be deleted and `lid` be still available?
Or will both `lid` and `tym` be deleted?

Comment: What is the point. Just try

Comment: Does that mean I should delete the question?

Comment: `del` reduces the reference count of a value; in effect, it erases the given name(s) as a reference to its object. It wouldn't make sense to delete an anonymous tuple, since its only reference would go away after the `del` statement anyway.

Comment: @chepner Not exactly, `del ((), (), ())` is totally valid, but `del (1, 2, 3)` is a `SyntaxError.`

Comment: @ruohola Because it's "recursing" on any iterable it finds; `del ((), (), ())` is effectively the same as `del ()`, and is basically a no-op, because it never finds a reference to actually delete. (Also, in Python's grammar, `1` et al. are literals, but `()` is not: it's an `atom`.

Comment: `del 1` is a syntax error; but compare `dis.dis("del ()")` or `dis.dis("((),(),())")` to `dis.dis("del a")`. Just because something *parses* doesn't mean it actually *does* anything.

Comment: @chepner True. Literals are atoms also though.

Comment: Yes, but the grammar only applies to *parsing*, not evaluation/execution, and it's not contested that `del ((), (), ())` parses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It deletes the variables:

```
>>> lid, tym = 1, 2
>>> del (lid, tym)
>>> lid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'lid' is not defined
>>> tym
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tym' is not defined
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement):

> #### 7.5. The `del` statement
>
> `del_stmt ::=  "del" target_list`
>
> ...
>
> Deletion of a target list recursively deletes each target, from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `del (a, b)` will delete the variables.

```py
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> t = (a, b)
>>> del (a, b)
>>> t
(1, 2)
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>>
```